# What difference does it makes when I use '' against ""?

Tags: php

What difference does it makes when I use  `''` against `""` ?

For example:

```
$example = 'Merry Christmas in Advance';
$eg = "Merry Christmas";

echo "$example";
echo '$example';


echo "$eg";
echo '$eg';
```

What would the output for each echo statements and what can we infer about `''` vs `""` in `PHP` ?

Comment: Not trying to be the grinch here, but there are 1mil+ results for http://www.google.com/search?q=single+quotes+vs+double+quotes+in+php

Comment: Where you unable to locate documentation or run that code yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$example = 'Merry Christmas in Advance';
$eg = "Merry Christmas";

echo "$example";
echo '$example';

echo "$eg";
echo '$eg';
```

would produce:

`Merry Christmas in Advance$exampleMerry Christmas$eg`

[Single quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) are handled literally.  No special characters (such as `\n`) or variables are interpolated.

[Double quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) will interpolate your variables and special characters and render them accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Single-quoted variables take input literally, double-quotes interpret escape sequences for special chars and expand variables.

You can see some good examples here:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Note that SOME escape sequences are still interpreted within single quotes.  Example:

> // Outputs: Arnold once said: "I'll be
>   back"
>
> echo 'Arnold once said: "I\'ll
>   be back"';

Comment: Lots of information is available on php.net: http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 2):

You can also include variables inside double quotes and those will be interpreted as variables, rather than strings

So:

```
$variable = 1;
echo 'this $variable' ==> will output 'this $variable'
echo "this $variable" ==> will output 'this 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes interpolate variables.